# Log4net does not write the log in the log file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, log4net, log4net-appender

I have created a simple scenario using Log4net, but it seems that my log appenders do not work because the messages are not added to the log file.

I added the following to the web.config file:

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false"/>        
</configSections>

<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
            <file value="D:\MyData\Desktop\LogFile.txt" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <encoding value="utf-8" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>


    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Within the global ASAX file I have added:

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));
```

And within the Application_Start method:

```
logger.Info("Starting the application...");
```

Why the test log "Starting the application..." is not being added to the log file?

Answer (score 335, accepted):

Do you call

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

somewhere to make log4net read your configuration? E.g. in Global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup

    // Initialize log4net.
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot that's it, I had the following line: log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(); 

Do I call this if I use the c# configuration instead of web.config to configure log4net? Is this "Configure"-Method call in any way required because in many tutorials I didn't find this line of code.

Comment: There are numerous ways to tell log4net where to look for configuration, see http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html. Calling XmlConfigurator.Configure() will make log4net look for configuration in <app.exe>.config or web.config. BasicConfigurator.Configure will (according to SDK docs): "Initializes the log4net logging system using a ConsoleAppender that will write to Console.Out."

Comment: FYI - you can also use log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator if you do NOT want it file based.  Output is sent to console.

Comment: I am doing the configuration in `AssemblyInfo` file. Posted as an answer below.

Comment: Argh, found so many of these questions and everywhere they fail to mention where to find the actual log files... Is it so obvious that everyone already knows?

Comment: No. It is not obvious at all. Lack of intuitive use is Log4Net's biggst flaw.

Answer (score 57):

Use this FAQ page:  [Apache log4net Frequently Asked Questions](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)

About 3/4 of the way down it tells you how to enable log4net debugging by using application tracing.  This will tell you where your issue is.

The basics are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And you see the trace in the standard output

Comment: Thanks I've checked the FAQ but these couldn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Thanks to this answer I was able to identify that my `root` section was referring to the wrong logger!!

Comment: great tip. I found that access was denied for asp.net user

Comment: if it doesn't work to someone, then please try my way to use this:
<log4net>
    <internal>
      <Debug value="true">
      </Debug>
    </internal>
</log4net>

Comment: this saved me x hours of headache.

Comment: Thought I was losing my mind, this really saved me. (In my case I had a converter that changed namespace in a refactor and I wasn't aware of this, so lo4net wasn't finding it)

Comment: Very useful, it showed were our logs were really stored

Answer (score 41):

Also, Make sure the ***"Copy always"*** option is selected for [log4net].config

[image]

Comment: This was the fix for me. I always forget this setting.

Answer (score 40):

As @AndreasPaulsson suggested, we need to configure it. I am doing the configuration in `AssemblyInfo` file. I specify the `configuration file name` here.

```
// Log4Net Configuration.
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

Comment: what happens if i have both this and log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); on load?

Comment: @n00b, then we can comment this line, actually only with this way it worked to me "log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();",

And one more thing : I added this in my web.config settings too
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>

Answer (score 26):

Make sure the process (account) that the site is running under has privileges to write to the output directory.

In IIS 7 and above this is configured on the application pool and is normally the [AppPool Identity](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/), which will not normally have permission to write to all directories.

Check your event logs (application and security) to see if any exceptions were thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your Help, also I thought about permission problems but also if I set on the folder read, write, modify, and execute permissions to everyone it does not work.

Comment: @john84 - are you getting exceptions? Have you looked at the event logs?

Comment: Also important, as I just discovered, with a Windows Service running under a specific account.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 22):

Insert:

```
 [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

at the end of **AssemblyInfo.cs** file

Comment: This was my rescue. Doing a desktop Forms project and putting log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); in main was  not helping. Thanks

Comment: this helped me. I had configuration in web.config but log4net seemed to not pick up the changes done. I added "Watch=true" to that attribute and anithing started working

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to give the `IIS_IUSRS` Read\write permission to the log file.

Answer (score 3):

For me I moved the location of the logfiles and it was only when I changed the name of the file to something else it started again.

It seems if there is a logfile with the same name already existing, nothing happens.

Afterwards I rename the old file and changed the log filename in the config back again to what it was.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, log4net wasn't logging properly due to having a space in my project name. Drove me nuts why the same code worked just fine in a different project, but didn't in the new one. Spaces. A simple space.

So, beware spaces in project names. I've learned my lesson.

Comment: Where did you have this issue? Log4Net is working great in one project, but not on another... don't know why. Tks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following line code should be there in AssemblyInfo.cs file.

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Web.config", Watch = true)]

and also check for this line in Application_start() method.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to move Logger to a Nuget Package. Below code need to be added in NuGet package project.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

See https://gurunadhduvvuru.wordpress.com/2020/04/30/log4net-issues-when-moved-it-to-a-nuget-package/ for more details.

Comment: Try to avoid links as answers. They may not always work. Perhaps edit your answer to include a summary of the info in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file seems correct. Then, you have to register your Log4net config file to application. So you can use below code:

```
var logRepo = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepo, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

After registering process, you can call below definition to call logger:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

log.Error("Sample log");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to use log4net.
I found it is useful while I was searching for a solution. The solution is described here: https://www.hemelix.com/log4net/