# Log4net doesn't write to file

Tags: c#, log4net

I want add new log to file.this is my appender:

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="mylogfile.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
    <stringToMatch value="test"/>
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
    <stringToMatch value="error"/>
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="All"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
```

and on my class I add

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

and I add access everyone for the file but: log4net doesn't write to file. Why?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Log4net fails silently when there's a problem. The design conceit is that no logging is preferable to taking down the application. To figure out what's wrong, turn on Log4net's internal debugging by adding this key to your [app/web].config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

The debug messages will be written to the console or to the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` system. More details from Phill Haack at http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/26/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/

There are any number of reasons Log4net might fail. Permissions problems on the log file directory, for starters (especially true for server processes, where your likely running under a restricted set of permissions for security).

Comment: Excelent tip! In 2 minutes solved an issue I had been stuck for an hour.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, until I realized the output for the debug goes to the Immediate window, not the Output one

Answer (score 3):

You just need to call Configure:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

You can see more details here:
[Log4net does not write the log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618380/log4net-does-not-write-the-log-file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the logging as the very first step in your app, and from the same assembly that you have the `[assembly]` tag:

From the [docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html):

> Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net
>   to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to
>   `LogManager.GetLogger` will cause the attributes on the calling assembly
>   to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging
>   call as early as possible during the application start-up, and
>   certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.**

Add something like this in your start up code:

```
LogManager.GetLogger("Initialises logging from assembly attributes");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this config section:

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net"     type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
```

to refer the log4net configuration.