# no content into log with log4net when writing windows service program

Tags: c#

I am configuration a commom.logging in windows service program.For now,it can generate the log file but no content in it.

I am using common.logging  and  log4net.

Here is my common.logging conf script:

```
        <configSections>
                <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
            <sectionGroup name="common">
                <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
            </sectionGroup>
        </configSections>
        <common>
            <logging>
                <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging">
                    <arg key="level" value="info" />
                    <arg key="showLogName" value="true" />
                    <arg key="showDataTime" value="true" />
                    <arg key="dateTimeFormat" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff" />
                </factoryAdapter>
            </logging>
        </common>
    </configuration>
```

and this is my log4net conf script:

```
<log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <root>                          
            <level value="ALL"/>
            <appender-ref ref="rollingFile"/>           
        </root>
        <logger name="ApplicationInfoLog">
            <level value="ALL"/>            
            <appender-ref ref="rollingFile"/>
        </logger>

        <appender name="rollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="Logs/a.txt"/>
            <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
            <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>           
            <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd&quot;.txt&quot;"/>
            <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">            
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] &lt;%X{auth}&gt; - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </log4net>
```

and this is the code who write content to the log:

```
namespace jsptpd
{
    public partial class jsptpdJobScheduler : ServiceBase
    {
        private readonly ILog logger;
        private IScheduler scheduler;

        public jsptpdJobScheduler()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            logger.Info("dfsfsd");
            logger.Debug("dsfsgg");            
        }
    }
}
```

Where proberbly wrong and i can't find it,please help me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4Net fails silently on the premise that no logging is better than taking down the application. If your log4net configuration works as expected, say, in a console application, and doesn't work in your service (daemon), the most likely problem is some sort of permissions issue.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841640/467473) to the question, [Log4net doesn't write to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818002/log4net-doesnt-write-to-file) for details on how to turn on log4net internal debugging. here's Phil Haack's take as well: http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/26/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

You maybe not using common.logging,you can configuration just using log4net like this:

```
    <configSections>
            <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>           
    </configSections>
```

And you can delete a logger just using root like this:

```
<log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <root>                          
            <level value="ALL"/>
            <appender-ref ref="rollingFile"/>           
        </root>
        <appender name="rollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="Logs/a.txt"/>
            <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
            <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>           
            <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd&quot;.txt&quot;"/>
            <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">            
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] &lt;%X{auth}&gt; - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </log4net>
```

It just using log4net and work fine.