# Logging in to File is not working using log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I am trying to use the log4net in my C# application for logging the exceptions. I have setup everything correctly but looks like I am missing something. Below is how I set up, ApiLogger class

```
public class ApiLogger
{
public static log4net.ILog GetLogger([CallerFilePath]string filename = "")
{
    return log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(filename);
 }
 }
```

App.Config

```
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level - %message%newline%exception"/>
   </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
     <file value="C:\tmp\Logs\JaxStrainMirror.log"/>
     <appendToFile value="true"/>
     <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
     <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
     <maximumFileSize value="100KB"/>
     <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
     <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
     <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %level - %message%newline%exception"/>
     </layout>
     </appender>
     <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
   <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
  </root>
  </log4net>
```

In the class

class CoreOdataClient
    {
    static log4net.ILog logger = UpdateCoreStrains.ApiLogger.GetLogger();

```
public static HttpClient client = null;

static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(string path, JrNumber jr)
{
    .............           
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(path, content);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        logger.Info("\n Failed");
```

But I dont see anything logged

[image]

Comment: Where are you calling XmlConfigurator.Configure?  If that's not the problem, some of the answers in the linked question might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4net does not write the log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618380/log4net-does-not-write-the-log-file)